# convert DocumentSnap shot object to Map<String, dynamic>flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to convert Firestore DocumentSnap shot object to Map<String, dynamic> but it gives an error.

**The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.**

```
factory LedgerMaster.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
final data = doc.data()!;
return LedgerMaster.fromJson(data).copyWith(id: doc.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;